# Undefined index: files when uploading using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a page that uploads an image. When I hit the upload.php I get this error

> Undefined index: files in E:\My-Laptop\Wamp\www\image-upload\upload.php on line 3

and if I do `print_r($_FILES)`I get an empty array.

I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Here is my code.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" >
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple>

            <!-- Drag and Drop container-->
            <div class="upload-area"  id="drop-zone">
                <h1>Drag and Drop file here<br/>Or<br/>Click to select file</h1>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');

    dropZone.ondrop = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var transfer = e.dataTransfer.files;

            uploadImage(transfer);
    }

    dropZone.ondragover = function(e){
        return false;
    }

    dropZone.ondragleave = function(e){
        return false;
    }
});

function uploadImage(files){
    var dataString = 'files='+files;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

my upload.php

```
<?php

    print_r($_FILES['files']);
```

Comment: here is an example to upload image using ajax https://www.dorcode.com/questions/50/auto-upload-picture

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's help:

```
function uploadImage(files){

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each( files, function( key, value ){
       data.append( key, value );
    });

   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```